# Stripe wont post to same page

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I' trying to use stripe checkout custom however I cant seem to get the following to post to the same page so the information can be processed, does anyone know what I'm missing here?

```
<form action="" method="POST">    
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

    <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

    <script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'example_key_123',
      image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function(token) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Open Checkout with further options:
      handler.open({
        name: 'Test',
        description: '2 widgets',
        currency: 'aud',
        amount: 2000
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
      handler.close();
    });
    </script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you just shared doesn't do anything with the token. The `token()` callback is empty so you basically create a card token but throw it away.

You need to customize `token()` to properly post the token to the page you want. It would also work with the same page. You can see a full example [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78626a38c4b4cb6932af) but the idea is that you have your own form and once the token is created, you add it to the form and submit it:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_XXXXX',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#payment-form").submit();
  }
});
```